# Log4Net propertyfilter match always

Tags: logging, filter, log4net

I want to log two different level according to method I am calling. I am using interception so I am trying to reach the goal with propery filter. Here my config:

```
<log4net>
 <appender name="DoWorkFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'_dowork.log'" />
    ...
   <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
      <key value="realMethod" />
      <stringToMatch value="DoWorkTest" />
      <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
   </filter>
 </appender>

 <appender name="WebsiteFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
   <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd'_website.log'" />
    ...
    <filter type="log4net.Filter.PropertyFilter">
       <key value="realMethod" />
       <stringToMatch value="DoWorkTest" />
       <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
    </filter>
  </appender>

  <root>
     <appender-ref ref="WebsiteFileAppender">
       <threshold value="ERROR" />
     </appender-ref>
     <appender-ref ref="DoWorkFileAppender">
       <threshold value="INFO" />
       </appender-ref>
   </root>
</log4net>
```

Now, If I call the metod `DoWorkTest`, everything woeks correctly and the message is written just in `*_dowork.log` file. But if I call another method that not match for example the method `anotherMethod`, the message is written in both files.

I have tried to replace the node `root` with this code:

```
<root>
  <level value="ALL" />
</root>
<logger name="WebSiteLogger">
  <level value="ERROR" />
  <appender-ref ref="WebsiteFileAppender" />
</logger>
<logger name="PaymentsLogger">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="DoWorkFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

But with this code no filter match.
What do I have to correct? Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps something is not clear? Can I improve my question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, your question interested me so I spent a little while trying things.  As I understand it, you need to be able to filter based on method name.  The problem is that a log can be created based on namespace and class, but not method name unless you hard code it.

In that case you would end up with something like this:

```
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        log4net.ILog log = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString() 
                                        + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
        log.Error("Logging an error from MyMethod");
    }
```

This would allow you to filter based on the method name:

Here is the filter for the appender which logs only calls from MyMethod:

```
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
            <!-- ...accept only logs from MyMethod -->
            <loggerToMatch value="Log4netTest.Form1.MyMethod" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="true" />
        </filter>
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.DenyAllFilter" />
```

Here is the other filter, which does NOT log MyMethod logs:

```
        <filter type="log4net.Filter.LoggerMatchFilter">
            <!-- ...don't accept logs from MyMethod -->
            <loggerToMatch value="Log4netTest.Form1.MyMethod" />
            <acceptOnMatch value="false" />
        </filter>
```

Now this gets the job done, but if you want a more generic way to log based on method name, try something like this:

```
    private void LogErrorByMethod(string message)
    {
        StackTrace stackTrace = new StackTrace();
        StackFrame frame = stackTrace.GetFrame(1);
        string fmname = frame.GetMethod().Name;

        string dt = System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType.ToString() + "." + fmname;
        log4net.ILog log2 = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(dt);

        log2.Error(message);
    }
```

Then you can just make your call from any method and your logs will be sorted according to method:

```
    private void MyMethod()
    {
        LogErrorByMethod("Logging from MyMethod");
    }
    private void Method2()
    {
        LogErrorByMethod("Logging from Method2");
    }
```

You'll have to have different methods for different levels, or pass in a level enum and use a switch, but you can use the stack trace to find out what method the call was made from and create a logger based on that.

Using LogByMethod will also allow you to use the %logger property in your pattern to include your method name in your logging message, but if you want to be even more explicit you can add a custom property:

```
        string fmname = frame.GetMethod().Name;
        log4net.GlobalContext.Properties["methodname"] = fmname;
```

Then your pattern can include:

...which is, admittedly, redundant if you already logging %logger, but it will allow you to separate the method name out automatically, like this:

```
<parameter>
<parameterName value="@method" />
<dbType value="String" />
<size value="100" />
<layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%property{methodname}" />
</layout>
</parameter>
```

And finally, just because I was on a roll, I thought of another way to do the filtering once you are able to log by method name.  Try this and you won't need the filters in the appenders at all:

```
    <logger name="Log4netTest.Form1.Method1" additivity="False">
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderMethod1"/>
    </logger>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppenderAllOtherMethods"/>
    </root>
```

Comment: SOrry, I have just came back to this project for some days. Just now I've tested your solution. It works perfectly. Thanx